# how to set path of bin folder in web.config which is inside the subdirectory asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How can i set the path of bin folder in the web.config file. My app is in the subdirectory folder and i want to set path for bin folder in the web.config to be set.
the root is mywebsite.com/cp/App/

the bin folder is in the cp folder . It is not in root directory

```
 what i have tried is 
 <runtime>
 <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
   <probing privatePath="..\bin"/>  
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: Why do you want to set the bin folder path in web.config?

Comment: I have change the directory of the web application to sub directory. So i need to give path of bin folder so that assembles loads.